# The operator += has inconsistent behavior with collections.Counter

Tags: python, collections, operator-keyword

```
In [20]: from collections import Counter

In [21]: x = [Counter()]

In [22]: z = x[0]

In [23]: z.update("w")

In [24]: z
Out[24]: Counter({'w': 1})

In [25]: x
Out[25]: [Counter({'w': 1})]

In [26]: z += Counter(["q"])

In [27]: z
Out[27]: Counter({'q': 1, 'w': 1})

In [28]: x
Out[28]: [Counter({'w': 1})]
```

I would have expected `x` to be `[Counter({'q': 1, 'w': 1})]`. What is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x += y` will effect another reference to `x` only if `x` has an `__iadd__` method.  If it has just `__add__`, `x += y` is the exact equivalent of `x = x + y`.  `collections.Counter` is something that does *not* have `__iadd__`, but does have `__add__`.  Because of that, `z += ...` is the same as `z = z + ...`, and you are just redefining `z` instead of modifying the object.  (I found that out by using `help(collections.Counter)` and searching for `__iadd__`.  It doesn't have it.)

Comment: Sounds like += is best avoided then. Thanks!